# Installing libyaml Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cygwin

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.

I've downloaded libyaml and ran ./configure, make and make install. They all seem to run successfully.

I'm using rvm and I'm not sure how to uninstall ruby in order to reinstall it. I've tried just running rvm install 1.9.3 and I've also tried rvm remove 1.9.3 and then running rvm install 1.9.3

Anyway, nothing is working. I'm still a noob when it comes to programming so apologies if I'm not making sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [Issue/Bug 5560](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5560) sounds very similar

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same problem. I've tried everything I can think of, nothing is working. The thread does sound similar though.